# how to get prev url in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button with search icon,And when user click on the search button url get change into the `/search` and search button icon's get change into the close icon,I want when user click on close icon get prev url...
**note : I use React-redux-universal-hot-example starter kit**
and this is my seach button with search icon.

```
 <Link className={`btn_search`}
                    to={"/search"}>
                <span>search_vlz</span>
 </Link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you can try something like this :

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class YourClass extends React.Component {

    goBack(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       this.context.router.goBack();
    }

    render(){

        return (
           <div onClick={this.goBack.bind(this)}> Go back</div>
        );
    }
}

YourClass.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Comment: tnx for answer...every thing is ok,but im have a problem when Im open new tab and directly get search component and click on close button im get in brwoser url...it's meaning it's not my website...im want check if prev url is not my website im handle handy get index route. :) tnx again,
how to handle this ?

Comment: Can you try lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`? There you'll have access to a new props with `nextProps` and with `this.props` to the old ones.

Comment: And With which property ?

Comment: Post jsfiddle and I'm going to see if I can do something. I need to see your code.

Comment: Im fixed that with check `history.length`. if length === 2 that mean prev url its browser new tab...it's a tricky but it's work fine.